# TornadoFX runAsyncWithProgress with nullable return type

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

In TornadoFX the `runAsyncWithProgress` function is currently (as of version 1.7.19) defined as:

```
fun <T : Any> Node.runAsyncWithProgress(progress: Node, op: () -> T): Task<T>
```

The `Any` bound on `T` prohibits me from using nullable types like `String?`. This is very inconvenient when the operation can have a 'null result' (by being cancelled for example).

I noticed that `runAsync` *does* support nullable values, is there a reason for this difference or is it some kind of oversight? I couldn't find anything in the source code that would cause issues with possibly-null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was indeed an oversight and has now been [fixed](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/issues/1128).